# MVC 4 - How to return a linq to entity query result in a view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

Using the next code in my controller Index action, I try to display 2 fields contents in a razor view:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
   public ActionResult Index()
      {
         IEnumerable<Prod> signatures = from Prod in db.Products
                                        select new Prod(Prod.ProductID, Prod.ProductName);
      }
}
```

Previously I have created a class in the models folder and named it "**Prod**":

```
public class Prod
{
   public int ProductID { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

But when I run the project I fall in the next error:

```
MyProject.Controllers.MyController.Index()
```

**not all code paths return a value**

Any help please ?

Comment: return View(signatures) is normally used, just show the view in your question.

Comment: A great place to start is http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: @jrummell, well noted, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sami-L, your Prod class does not have specialized constructor, that is, a constructor that accepts some initialization values. Your action should be something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Prod> signatures = from p in db.Products
                                    select new Prod
                                    {
                                        ProductId = p.ProductID, 
                                        ProductName = p.ProductName
                                    };
    return View(signatures); 
}
```

Note the curly braces "{" instead of "(" braces. This should help solve the constructor error which you are getting.

UPDATE: I've renamed a parameter in your LINQ query from `Prod` to `p`. Using Prod the way you specified made compiler think that your ProductID and ProductName were static properties. By renaming the parameter after `from` this should help solve the issue.

Comment: I've tried out your proposal and got the Error **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MyProject.Models.Prod.ProductID.get'**

Answer (score 3):

I think you are simply missing the `return` statement.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Prod> signatures = from Prod in db.Products
                                        select new Prod(Prod.ProductID, Prod.ProductName);
    return View(signatures);  // this is missing
}
```

Comment: @David, Yes of course this is a stupid error, I used             **return View(signatures)**; and it worked but then got the next error at the view level: "**Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities**" The error points at **@foreach( var item in Model )**, please kindly help me to resolve this since I am new to MVC.

Comment: @Sami-L Add a parameterless constructor to your `Product` entity (you can make it protected if you don't want to expose it)

Comment: @DavinTryon, return signatures returns an object of type IEnumerable<Prod> and not an object that inherits from ActionResult.

Comment: @Husein, so what to do at last ? I have this on the top of my view: **@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Prod>**

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `return` element. You will need to wrap this in a `View` so that your Index razor view will be passed the Prod list.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Prod> signatures = from Prod in db.Products
                                   select new Prod(Prod.ProductID, Prod.ProductName);
    return View(signatures);  // add this
}
```

In the Index.cshtml you can also declare the model so the view is strongly typed, i.e.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Prod>

<table>
  @foreach(var prod in Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@prod.ProductID</td>
      <td>@prod.ProductName</td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```